# Как исправить ошибку в функции (pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Создал срез grade. В нем находится информация об оценка по математике(math score), чтению(reading score), письму(writing score) и общая оценка Grade.

```py
grade = df[['math score', 'reading score', 'writing score']].astype('int')
grades = []
    
for line in grade.values:
    if line.mean() > 90:
        grades.append('A')
    elif line.mean() > 80 and line.mean() <= 90:
        grades.append('B')
    elif line.mean() > 70 and line.mean() <= 80:
        grades.append('C')
    elif line.mean() > 60 and line.mean() <= 70:
        grades.append('D')
    elif line.mean() > 50 and line.mean() <= 60:
        grades.append('E')
    elif line.mean() <= 50:
        grades.append('F(Fail)')
        
grade['Grade'] = grades
```

[image: Frame]

Нужно написать функцию, которая будет принимать в себя оценку(A, B, C, D, E или F) и на выход выдавать сколько человек получило оценку, которая была подана в функцию. Написал вот такую функцию, но выдает ошибку

```py
def GetGrade(average_mark):
    counter_of_marks = grade.Grade.value_counts()[avarage_mark]
    
    return print(f'Оценку {avarage_mark} получили {counter_of_mark} человек')

GetGrade(input())
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16348/2346298494.py in <module>
     26 grade['Grade'] = grades
     27 
---> 28 GetGrade(input())

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16348/2346298494.py in GetGrade(average_mark)
      1 def GetGrade(average_mark):
      2     # your code here
----> 3     counter_of_marks = grade.Grade.value_counts()[avarage_mark]
      4 
      5     return print(f'Оценку {avarage_mark} получили {counter_of_mark} человек')

NameError: name 'avarage_mark' is not defined
```

Подскажите как исправить, пожалуйста

Comment: Ну там же написано, что нет такой переменной `avarage_mark`, проверьте третью букву, там должна быть `e`, а не `a`, как в заголовке функции: `def GetGrade(average_mark):`

Comment: только что заметил, извините

Comment: Такое бывает, первым делом при такой ошибке ищите проблемное имя по коду прямо поиском, и тогда быстро можно понять, в чём дело - в теле функции она бы нашлась, а в заголовке не нашлась бы.